# subprocess.call env var

Tags: python, environment-variables, call, subprocess, popen

I'm using Popen because I need the env, like this:

```
Popen(
    ["boto-rsync", "..."],
    env={"PATH":"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/"},
    )
```

The problem is `Popen` runs the command as a new thread. Is there any way that I could pass the `env` to `subprocess.call` or prevent `Popen` from creating a new thread?
Thanx

Comment: unrelated: `Popen()` does NOT create a new thread (it creates a new *process*).

Comment: Just a reminder, `env` replaces the current environment. If you only want to modify it, create a copy first: `new_env = dict(os.environ); new_env['PATH'] = path; Popen(args, env=new_env)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `env` with call in the exact same way as with `popen`:

```
subprocess.call(
    ["boto-rsync", "..."],
    env={"PATH":"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/"},
    )
```

Comment: Thanx, I don't know why I didn't try it ! I think I couldn't find the option.

Comment: @AliBZ the documentation for [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is not clear on that point -- the only indication that other keyword args are supported is the tiny little asterisk in `subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`

Comment: @AliBZ: to be clear: `subprocess.call(cmd)` is just `subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()` i.e., you may pass to `call()` all arguments that you may pass to `Popen()`.