# Automate azure azcopy using python on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azcopy

**I am trying to use *azcopy* from python,** I have already used this from *CLI* and it is working!

I have successfully executted the following commands:

for upload :

```
set AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET=<my client secret>
azcopy login --service-principal --application-id=<removed> --tenant-id=<removed>
azcopy copy "D:\azure\content" "https://dummyvalue.blob.core.windows.net/container1/result4" --overwrite=prompt --follow-symlinks --recursive --from-to=LocalBlob --blob-type=Detect
```

Similarly for download

```
azcopy copy "https://dummyvalue.blob.core.windows.net/container1/result4" "D:\azure\azcopy_windows_amd64_10.4.3\temp\result2" --recursive
```

Now, **I want to automate these commands using python**, I know that azcopy can also be used using SAS keys but that is out of scope for my working

First attempt:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["azcopy", "login", "--service-principal", "--application-id=<removed>", "--tenant-id=<removed>"])
```

Second attempt:

```
import os
os.system("azcopy login --service-principal --application-id=<removed> --tenant-id=<removed>")
```

I have already `set AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET` in my environment.

I am using python 3 on windows.

Every time I get this error:

> Failed to perform login command:  service principal auth requires an
>   application ID, and client secret/certificate
>
> NOTE: If your credential was created in the last 5 minutes, please
>   wait a few minutes and try again.

I don't want to use Azure VM to do this job

Could anyone please help me fix this problem?

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350669/subprocess-call-env-var. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `set` cmd does not set a permanent environment variable, it only takes effect in the current windows cmd prompt.

You should **manually set the environment variable via UI** or try to use `setx` command.

I did a test by using your code, and **manually set the environment variable** of `AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET` as per UI, then the code can run without issues(it may take a few minutes to take effect).

Test result is as below:

[image]