# the fastest way to move thousands of blob files from a container to another in python azure web app?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, batch-processing

I want to copy thousands of blob files from a container to another inside a python azure web app.
The python azure-storage-blob library doesn't provide methods for batch copies. What is the fastest way to do it? I found blobxfer (an advanced data movement tool and library for Azure Storage Blob and Files) but no example of code using it!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be using AzCopy, which you can call using Python too. Take a look on this previous question / answer:

[Automate azure azcopy using python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151754/automate-azure-azcopy-using-python-on-windows)

Comment: Can it be run from inside Python Azure WebApp?

Comment: Yes, you can containerize an app and run it on Web App. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/423