# access environment variable inside maya via subprocess

Tags: python, maya

Need to call maya using a subprocess i.e.

subprocess.check_call([maya_bin] + sys.argv[1:], env=os.environ)

and environment variable being passed like above. Problem is

QT_PLUGIN_PATH env when queried inside maya at runtime shows nothing.

So how does one make all environment variables accessible within maya

Before calling maya ,

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH = '/fb/NHI/fifth/qt/4.8.5_5.6.1/4.8.5/Linux/plugins:/fb/NHI/fifth/maestro/plugins:/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins'
```

After maya is initiated, its only,

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH = '/fb/NHI/fifth/qt/4.8.5_5.6.1/4.8.5/Linux/plugins'
```

it should be

```
'/fb/NHI/fifth/qt/4.8.5_5.6.1/4.8.5/Linux/plugins:/fb/NHI/fifth/maestro/plugins:/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins'
```

How is it possible ?

Comment: Could you try if it works like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment   Are you using shell? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment#comment88233951_4453495

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350669/subprocess-call-env-var

Comment: Could you try if it works to pass in some other variable like that?

Comment: I've tried this. Question is as Maya opens this variable value is reset. How to ensure that what is passed is what it shows